# How to find out from which line number the method was called in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Let us have a following simple example:

```
def funny_function(param)
  lineNumber = __LINE__  # this gives me the current line number
  puts lineNumber
end
```

As we can see, I can get the current line number. However, my question is, **is there a non-intrusive way to find out from which line number (and even a file) the method was called?**

Non-intrusive meaning that I don't want the method user to know about that, she just has to provide the `param` parameter, e.g.:

```
funny_function 'Haha'
```

Maybe something like `caller.__LINE__`?

Comment: What is wrong with the response of the `caller` method?

Comment: `caller` returns the current execution stack, in the format: `file:line: in \`method'`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: just did not want to parse it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `caller_locations` which has been added recently. It returns an array of `Location` objects. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html for details.

No need to parse the return of `caller`. Hooray.

To add on to this `caller_locations.first` or `caller_locations(0)` gets the last method location, increment the parameter to pull specific steps.

Answer (score 2):

```
def b
  puts "world"
end

def a
  puts "hello"
end

p method(:a).source_location
=> ["filename.rb", 5]
```

Is this what your after?

Comment: no, he is looking for the line number where the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

To get the line of the ast function call `caller[0].scan(/\d+/).first` :

```
def func0
  func1
end

def func1
  func2
end


def func2
  func3
end

def func3
  p caller[0].scan(/\d+/).first
end

func0
```

Comment: using caller_locations will spare you from parsing strings.

Comment: @pascalbetz I did not know it, I saw your answer afterwards which is way better. I just did not edit my answer because it works and also it gives an alternative way of doing it. Also, I did not want to paraphrase your answer.

Comment: Yes, the method was only added recently. It's also said to be more performant.